# Is there a quicker way paste a lot of data into an Excel Table?

Tags: excel, vba

As part of my code I create a new sheet import 3 sheets of data into that new sheet and then when it's finished tidying up the data I clear a table and then paste the data into it. This on average takes about 6 minutes. I can't delete the table as it is being referenced else where.

The code I have is:

```
' Clear the table of the data you are going to import to
importTable.DataBodyRange.Delete
' Delete the first row of the new sheet as this is not needed
WS3.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
' Copy the data and then add it to the table,
' when finished delete the new sheet as it's not required any more
WS3.UsedRange.Copy
WS2.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
WS3.Delete
```

35k lines of data I need to paste in. I don't know any different but would looping through the data to paste it in line by line be any quicker ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [load data to array and write back to cells in the table](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman would that be a 2 dimension array ?

Comment: Yes it would....

Comment: @BigBen i'll have a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
' Clear the table of the data you are going to import to
importTable.DataBodyRange.Delete
' Delete the first row of the new sheet as this is not needed
WS3.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
' Copy the data and then add it to the table,
' when finished delete the new sheet as it's not required any more
With WS3.UsedRange
  WS2.Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
end with
WS3.Delete
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Time taken before = 6 Mins+
Time taken now = 32 seconds. thank you